# Pyboto: remove an ip based rule from a security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I've been reading through the Pyboto [documentation](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/2.6.0/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.securitygroup) and whilst I know how to *add* an ip-based rule to a security group, I have not been able to find a method remove an ip-based rule. The method remove_rule on a security group object, doesn't update the security group on the ec2 instance - so I'm not sure that will help me either.

Has anyone accomplished this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `SecurityGroup` object in boto has two important methods; `authorize` and `revoke`.  The easiest way to add and remove rules to a group is to use these methods.  So, to add an IP-based rule:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')  # or whatever region you want
sg = conn.get_all_security_groups('my_security_group')[0]
sg.authorize('tcp', 22, 22, cidr_ip='0.0.0.0/0')
```

This would authorize port 22 for all hosts.  To revoke that rule (and you should!):

```
sg.revoke('tcp', 22, 22, cidr_ip='0.0.0.0/0')
```

Its the same arguments.

Comment: Thank you - how do I return a list of ip-based rules for a security group?

Comment: You can't get a list of only ip-based rules but you can get a list of all rules for a security group using the ``rules`` attribute of the ``SecurityGroup`` object.  Each of the objects in this list will, in turn, have a ``grants`` attribute which is a list of the explicit grants associated with the rule.  If that object has a non-None value for the attribute ``cidr_ip`` then it is an IP-based rule.